# Forms Authentication update user status after specific user session ends

Tags: c#, asp.net

Hi I'm using Forms Authentication for authentication users in my asp.net c# application. How can I update user status after specific user session ends (automatically) or browser close?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Depends on how you're storing session.

If you're using InProc, then you can hook into the Session_End application event in Global.asax:

```
protected void Session_End(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Remove user session
}
```

If you're not using InProc (ie you're using SQLState, ASP.NET State Service, etc), then you'll need to write a custom HttpModule. [Here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/SessionEndStatePersister.aspx) is a decent example on codeproject.

Note that this will only handle expired sessions, ie server-side session.

A browser close is a client-side event, so to handle a browser close event immediately (ie not relying on the timeout to happen some time later on the server), you'll need to write client-side code.

You're best bet is hook into the *onbeforeunload* event:

```
<body onbeforeunload="handleBrowserCloseEvent()">
```

The function will need to make an AJAX call to your server to expire the session.

Hope that helps.

Comment: What I'm trying to achieve is when user is online I want to show him as he is online and when he is session expired I would like to show him offline. I'm changing his status in sql table IsOnline false or true. Its easy to show on login and logout events. but I'ms not sure how to update the sql database after his session expired. Maybe you have a better solution how to achieve the same results... Thank you

Comment: I dont understand what you're asking - are you storing your session in the SQL State Database? How are you "changing his status in sql table"? is this a custom table? You should be letting the SQL State Database handle the actual database-side of the anonymous/authenticated session logic.

Comment: I'm storing in SQL database. On login or logout events updating IsOnline field using linq queries

Comment: That's a very strange way of dealing with session. It defeats the whole point of ASP.NET State. When you do Session["BobLoggedIn"] = true, this will serialize this data to your chosen state provider (ie SQL State database). You shouldnt be physically running linq queries to try and record session. Think u need to have a read of ASP.NET State Management.